# maven 3.6.3 build with jdk11 not finding Java system classes like Object, String

Tags: java, maven, java-11, rhel7

When I try to build a fairly simple Maven project using Maven 3.6.3 and jdk11, Maven starts all right and goes through the first few operations. When it gets to compiling, though, I get many errors similar to “The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files”.

This seems to be symptomatic of javac not finding the Java system libraries, but a simple “hello world” program compiles and runs using the “javac” and “java” commands.

I’m using the AdoptOpenJDK jdk11-11.0.9.1+1 on RHEL 7.8. I have the JAVA_HOME env var set to the dir it’s installed in /opt/jdk11-11.0.9.1+1. I have tried it with and without an M2_HOME pointing to the Maven dir (I was surprised to see M2_HOME is effectively deprecated).

This is using the maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1, with the <release>11</release> configuration.

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.zephyr</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-producer-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Kafka Streams Quickstart :: Java</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kafka.version>2.6.0</kafka.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!--
                Execute "mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar"
                to build a jar file out of this project!
        -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5</version>
              <configuration>
                <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                            <version>0.21.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.4,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>single</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Kafka dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Do you have an example project by which you can reproduce this on your system on Github or alike?

Comment: We probably need the pom.xml to see how the maven compiler  plugin is being called and what JDK it points to.

Comment: Added pom.xml, this is a very slightly modified Apache Kafka example.

Comment: Do you like to use tycho compiler? or JDK 11 apart from that you are using an extreme older definition of tycho-compiler-jdt (0.21.0 is from 2014!!) ... Remove the configuration in pluginManagement only define the plugin versions ... and maybe the release configuration...

Answer (score 0):

We've seen issues with a similar set-up. Try upgrading to Maven 3.8.1.